# How to control/change the unit of measurement precision of the ruler?

Tags: measurement

How to change the ruler's unit of measurement precision to show only 10ths, 100ths, 1000ths, etc. appropriate to the scene (e.g. architectural vs precision machining).

Example: x to y measurement = 13.00657.

Require: x to y = 13.0 (instead of going to the Nth place beyond the decimal).

Where to change the ruler's unit precision?

Comment: I don't think there's any explicit unit precision control, you can insert any value in the boxes. You can choose what units to use and how from the *Properties Window > Scene > Units* section

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Docs don't mention how to do that: [link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/interface/ruler_and_protractor.html#shortcuts). Can you explain how to change the number inside the ruler bubble? I get arc/angle options on click and options listed at link url.

Comment: I don't think that is possible the ruler always reflects the clicked distance to the maximum possible precision